# How to create an already-resolved future

Tags: c++, c++11, stdasync, std-future

I have a function that returns a `std::future`. I have added a cache to the implementation, and I would like to optionally return a value immediately if it does not need to be recalculated.

How can I create an already-resolved future?

```cpp
// Class declarations shortened to minimal example to communicate intent
class MyClass {
    Cache m_cache;

    std::future<int> foo(int arg);
}

class Cache {
    std::optional<int> get(int arg);
}

std::future<int> MyClass::foo(int arg) {
    if (auto res = m_cache.get(arg)) {
        // *res is my result
        return std::future(*res); // ????? Doesn't work
    }
    // If the cache misses, we need to calculate it
    // Fire up the ol' thread pool and get to work
    return std::launch(std::launch::async /* ommited for brevity */);
}
```

I'm targeting C++20.

Comment: Unrelated to your actual question, Java's `concurrentHashMap` has locks on each *entry* in the "cache", and on a cache miss, it will insert a locked placeholder, and then fire async work to "calculate the value and unlock the entry". That way, if many threads ask for the same cache-miss item, only one calculates it, and the rest simply block, and thus each entry is only calculated exactly once.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only `std::async`, `std::packaged_task` and `std::promise` can create futures with new states.

`std::promise` is the easiest way:

```cpp
std::future<int> MyClass::foo(int arg) {
    if (auto res = m_cache.get(arg)) {
        // *res is my result
        std::promise<int> p;
        p.set_value(*res);
        return p.get_future();
    }
    // If the cache misses, we need to calculate it
    // Fire up the ol' thread pool and get to work
    return std::launch(std::launch::async /* ommited for brevity */);
}
```

```cpp
// Or with a helper function
template<typename T>
std::future<std::decay_t<T>> make_ready_future(T&& value) {
    std::promise<std::decay_t<T>> p;
    p.set_value(std::forward<T>(value));
    return p.get_future();
}

std::future<int> MyClass::foo(int arg) {
    if (auto res = m_cache.get(arg)) {
        // *res is my result
        return make_ready_future(*res);
    }
    // If the cache misses, we need to calculate it
    // Fire up the ol' thread pool and get to work
    return std::launch(std::launch::async /* ommited for brevity */);
}
```

Comment: @MooingDuck I mean, at least that gives us a list of names to avoid.